# What does the line "listening to blackstreet" mean in the song *Downtown* by Macklemore and Ryan Lewis?

Tags: lyrics, meaning, rap

Here is a [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JGhoLcsr8GA) to the song.

I was wondering what the phrase "listening to blackstreet" means.

The whole sentence before it says

> ...I Like a Big Girl, I like 'Em Sassy
>   Going down the Backstreet listening to Blackstreet
>   Running around the whole town...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Blackstreet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackstreet) is an R&B group most popular in the 90s. Their most well-known song is probably ["No Diggity"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3KL9mRus19o), a number one hit featuring Dr. Dre.

The [lyrics annotation](http://genius.com/7699756) of "Downtown" on Genius.com confirms this as well.